# Two NOTE messages from R CMD check --as-cran

Tags: r, cran

In the process of submitting an R package to CRAN, I could not resolve two issues
the reviewer encountered on his system:

1.)

```
Package has help file(s) containing build-stage \Sexpr{} expresssons but no 'build/partial.rdb' file.
```

2.)

```
Checking URLs failed with message:
/home/tmp/CRAN/mypackage.Rcheck/00_pkg_src/mypackage/man/mypackage-package.Rd:6: file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ does not exist
```

The DESCRIPTION-file is included in the right place.
Unfortunately I cannot give any additional details at this point, because I could not reproduce these
messages on my system and could not figure out their meaning.

What would be possible reasons for these messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the issues were. The function `package.skeleton()` I used, which automates some of the setup of a new package, uses the following
commands in the automatically generated documentation file `mypackage-package.Rd`: `\packageTitle{}`, `\packageDescription{}`, `\packageAuthor{}` and `\packageMaintainer{}`.

The latter commands use build-stage \Sexpr{} expressions. This and the fact that
the file `build/partial.rdb` was not present lead to the first NOTE message. Note that `build/partial.rdb` is not generated automatically by `package.skeleton()`.

The reason for the second NOTE message is very similar: The command `\packageTitle{}` relates to the DESCRIPTION file in order to extract the package title from the field `Title:`. However, `\packageTitle{}` could not find the DESCRIPTION file.

As a solution to these problems I did no longer use the commands `\packageTitle{}`, `\packageDescription{}`, `\packageAuthor{}` and `\packageMaintainer{}`, but wrote the respective texts in the documentation file `mypackage-package.Rd` directly.

Answer (score 0):

We created a specific mailing list [r-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel) for these questions. You should probably post there.

And you will need to provide more details, preferably reproducible ones.  Right now all I can tell you is that you local errors.  Compare against a working package that checks correctly --- CRAN has over 7000 of them.