# "The DESCRIPTION file: This package was not yet installed at build time."

Tags: r, cran, r-package

In the manual of my just created package, I find under "details" the sentences:

```
The DESCRIPTION file: This package was not yet installed at build time."
Index: This package was not yet installed at build time.
```

This does not sound good. But of course, a package has to be build at first, then it can be installed. I don't understand what this message means and how I can get rid of it. When I type the message in google I get other pdf manuals with the same message. There are also CRAN packages with this message. So the message is not a tragedy?

Comment: I suspect you simply have to install the package, then build it again. That's certainly my workflow.  The index is simply a list of the page numbers in the manual where the functions occur, so not having this is certainly not a tragedy.  But easy to fix, so you may as well fix this.

Comment: What's your build workflow look like?

Answer (score 1):

My built workflow (hope that I understood what you meant, @Thomas) is:

```
system("R CMD check Path_to_package/pname")
system("R CMD build Path_to_package/pname")
system("R CMD check --as-cran C:/R-3.2.2/pname_version.tar.gz")
```

With option --as-cran I got the same messages as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357637/two-note-messages-from-r-cmd-check-as-cran). I deleted now all the automatically generated commands as e.g. `\packageDescription{}` in the .Rd files. Now the notes from this thread as well as [these notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357637/two-note-messages-from-r-cmd-check-as-cran) do not appear any more.

Comment: You never need to run `R CMD check` on the package directory, only the source tarball. You will get all sorts of weird errors if you do that. So, just skip the first step.